# Is it correct to use stringstream with char*

Tags: c++

I have a vector of string object :

I need to convert it into char* using stringstream and store char* in a vector.
is it right way to do it?

```
//! strvector contain string objects and newcharvector needs to be populate. 
for(int i =0 ; i < strvector.size(); i++)
{
    std::string &obj = strvector[i];
    std::stringstream ss;
    char* str;
    ss << obj;
    ss >> str;
    newcharvector.push_back(str);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if explain reason of downvote

Comment: `str` is an uninitialized pointer, how can this work at all?

Comment: So I need to create duplicate of obj.c_str()  and then store it in vector . Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char*` is a pointer that points to a memory area that contains the string.

In your example: Where is this memory/the string?
Of course, `stringstream` (which should not be used anymore, use `istringstream` or `ostringstream`) internally stores the string, and you could retrieve the string from it, but the moment that the `stringstream` object is deleted, the internal string is deleted and your `char*` pointer points to free/unused memory (which will most likely be re-used by the next instance of the `stringstream` variable).

For storing a `char*` in a `vector` you would have to take a tour of the dynamic memory allocation wonderland. Don't (yet).

Why don't you store `std::string`s in your `vector`?

Comment: strings in a vector is the place he's starting from so it's clear the OP doesn't want to do that. But why he wants pointers in a vector still hasn't been explained. It's dubious of course but when the OP doesn't want to explain it's hard to advise.

Comment: Its a legacy code which restrict me ti use char* . But I solve it by using strdup. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use raw pointers!

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> strvector{ "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "thud" };
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<char[]>> newcharvector;

    for (auto const &s : strvector) {
        newcharvector.push_back(std::shared_ptr<char[]>(new char[s.length() + 1]));
        std::strcpy(newcharvector.back().get(), s.c_str());
    }

    for (auto const &s : newcharvector)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right way to do it?

It's rather roundabout. Better just use `c_str()` to get the string representation represented as `char*`, and then use `strdup()` to persist that string (if that's necessary, because the pointer returned by `c_str()` is invalid as soon as you modify the `std::string` or it goes out of scope)

```
std::vector<std::string> strvector{ "foo", "bar" };
    std::vector<char*> pointers;
    for (std::string &s : strvector) {
        pointers.push_back(_strdup(s.c_str()));
    }

    for (char* p : pointers) {
        printf("string: %s\n", p);
    }
```